How to automatically add a class to paragraph elements in ckeditor5?
When a paragraph is added to the wysiwyg, I want ckeditor to automatically add a class to it (dynamically in the wysiwyg), such that if I click "source" after the wysiwyg adds a new paragraph, I should see <p class="myclass">.
